# Issue with EXPORT to CSV FILE

Tags: php, html, csv

I Want to export what i write in input text for that :

-I have created a class called "ExcelFile", that contain methods for exporting data to csv file.

-I have an issue, when i try to export this file with data, a colone is added automatically in csv file, this colone contain the code html of my table

-This is my code :

### ExcelFile.php

```
<?php
class ExcelFile {

    private
    $csv = Null;

    function Colonne($file) {

        $this->csv.=$file."\n";
        return $this->csv;

    }


    function Insertion($file){

        $this->csv.=$file."\n";
        return $this->csv;
    }


    function output($NomFichier){

        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$NomFichier.csv");
        print $this->csv;
        exit;

    }
}

?>
```

### Index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'ExcelFile.php';
?>
<html>

<form method='post' action="index.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>First Name</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tfirst' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tlast' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' name='btnsave' value='Export Csv File' /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</html>
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ["btnsave"] )) {

    test ();
}
function test() {
    $Excelfile = new ExcelFile ();
    $Excelfile->Colonne ( "First Name;Last Name" );
    $Excelfile->Insertion ( $_POST ['tfirst'] . ';' . $_POST ['tlast'] );
    $Excelfile->output ( 'Export result' );

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output() function is called after you have already sent the whole HTML document, so that is why it is included in your file.

You need to move the code around a bit so your index.php file looks more like this:

```
<?php
include_once 'ExcelFile.php';

if (isset ( $_POST ["btnsave"] )) {

    test ();
    exit; //you want to end here, so the html below is not in the CSV
}

function test() {
    $Excelfile = new ExcelFile ();
    $Excelfile->Colonne ( "First Name;Last Name" );
    $Excelfile->Insertion ( $_POST ['tfirst'] . ';' . $_POST ['tlast'] );
    $Excelfile->output ( 'Export result' );

}
?>
<html>

<form method='post' action="index.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>First Name</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tfirst' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tlast' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' name='btnsave' value='Export Csv File' /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

(Side note: please consider using a PHP framework)

(Side note: please consider using commas to separate the values instead of semi-colons)